# Best practice for mixed binary/text logging in C++

Tags: c++, logging

In C++, is there a logging framework for logging both binary data (e.g. POD messages with pre-defined format), as well as text data (for informational purposes)?

As an example, consider we have a POD type

```
struct EmployeeInfo
{
  unsigned int age;
  char name[80];
}
```

At startup (say at 00:00:00.001), we may want to emit a text log entry saying "Employee DB app started".
Then at 00:00:00.002, we received a new EmployeeInfo, so we may want to emit a binary log entry containing the EmployeeInfo data.

There's some benefit using a single log file for both types of events, in that order relationship among the events is maintained. The format of entries in the log file does not matter (it doesn't need to be human readable), as long as given a log file, it's easy to write two separate utitlity programs, one for processing (e.g. pretty printing) all EmployeeInfo info in the file, one for processing (e.g. printing to cout) all the text entries in it.

It appears that most existing logging frameworks in C++ (e.g. g2log, glog, spdlog etc.) are for generating human readable text log files only, and the usage is typically similar to printf or  outputting to a stream, e.g.:

```
LOGD << "Hello %s!" << "World";
```

An obvious way to achieve the "one-file" requirement is to simply design a common message format for both events, e.g. timestamp + length + type + real data, and then simply write to a binary file. The drawbacks are: 1) The format of logging statement may not be as natural as in existing logging frameworks, 2) we need extra code if e.g. we want some features offered by existing logging frameworks, such as automatic rotation of log files every day.

I thought mixed binary/text logging should be a relatively common scenario, but I cannot seem to find any existing C++ libraries for it. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: spdlog offers every day log feature, and you are able to set up custom formatting

Comment: If I needed to display the contents of the struct, I would overload the operator<< to do it.  That avoids the binary issue altogether, and keeps the knowledge in the struct where it belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that mixed binary & text logging is common. I never heard of that.

What you might consider is logging only text, but emit in that text some (printable) "identifiers" (perhaps inspired by [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)s) which refer to some *other* binary file (for example, an [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) database). So you would emit `Hello from _9oXtCgAbkqv` and store in another database some binary data related to `_9oXtCgAbkqv`. BTW that "identifier" might even be some file offset inside some other binary file.

BTW, if you emit any kind of binary log-like data, you need to have an utility to inspect that binary data. (For textual files, this is not an issue, since standard textual utilities like Linux commands `less`, `grep`,  `awk`, `tail`, `head`, `split` are enough).

And your issue is not C++ specific (you could have it in Ocaml, Python, Rust, Common Lisp, etc...). It is a matter of habits, conventions, operating systems, etc... Notice that log files are mostly *conventional*, and that utilities like [logrotate](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/understanding-logrotate-utility/) can manage several log files.